# Java DecimalFormat (and taglib fmt:formatNumber) are formatting 0.00 as --0.00

Tags: java, jsp, ibm-midrange, taglib, decimalformat

A customer just converted their IBM i system to be on a Power 9.

I have an application running on Tomcat, locally on the IBM i.  And when I perform a DecimalFormat(0.00).format(i), where "i" is a double with a value of 0.00, the text results in --0.00.
And, as stated in the title, this is also occurring on the taglib

Odd thing is if I change the double value to be an int, 0, then the value returns correctly as 0.

So, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
new java.text.DecimalFormat("#.00").format(0)   
new java.text.DecimalFormat("#.00").format(0.00)
new java.text.DecimalFormat("#.00").format(0.10)
```

Results in:
0
--0.00
.10

Comment: What locale is  your app running with?  Just upgrading to new hardware should make no difference at all. That said, the new hardware probably has a new Java install and different defaults could be making a difference.

Comment: Also, is the system current on Java Group PTF's?

Comment: I agree with your first comment. I ran a class.getResource on DecimalFormat.class, and it showed, /QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk80/32bit/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/text/DecimalFormat.class.  And the following are values pulled from Tomcat's catalina.out during startup.                                                                                                  
**Java Home:             /QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk80/32bit/jre
JVM Version:           8.0.5.5 - pap3280sr5fp5-20171114_01(SR5 FP5)  
JVM Vendor:            IBM Corporation**

Comment: I would talking to your customers system admin about the Java group PTF level.  The current ptf levels can be found here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas4PSPbyNum

Comment: Thanks.  They are at level 7, where IBM's is at 10.  But, again, oddly enough this started when they changed systems.  But, I'll get them to upgrade, and will get back to you.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that when i run a java class, executing the same DecimalFormat calls, from a class in QSHELL, the value come out just fine.  So, my thought is that something is effecting Tomcat.